# Azure Website deploys from Visual studio but does show empty in browser

Tags: asp.net, azure, deploying

I have been using Azure websites, and deploying from VS2013 for a while. However, this morning I ran into a strange problem.

- I created a ASP.NET website in the Free Tier for Azure
- I downloaded the publish manifest from the Azure
- Imported the publish file into Visual Studio 2012
- I deploy the site from within VS, and there are no errors (there is nothing different from other deployments I have done)
- After deployment, it launches the site. "The website has been created successfully, but there is nothing here"

#### Steps Tried

1. looked into the operation logs
2. looked into the FTP log; neither of them have any entry for the deployment
3. I have stopped and started the website
4. I have restarted the site

Comment: What's the deployment path set to? i.e. ftp://*.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot - this should be in the publish file. And have you connected via FTP to check the files are where they should be?

Comment: The text in your last bullet point sounds like the default "home" page created automatically for an Azure website. In the Websites section of the Portal, click on your site and then go to the Configure tab. Scroll down to the "default documents" section and remove the `hostingstart.html` entry. Your intended home page should display afterwards.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. Deleting the hostingstart.html page resolved the problem.  FYI, i had tried both the FTP and Webdeploy.